# GHUnit as test bundle instead of separate target

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocunit, gh-unit

Is it possible to create Test Bundle with OCUnit for unit tests, but instead OCUnit use GHUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if it is possible to use the `GHUnit` test runner for regular `OCUnit`/`SenTestCase` tests? If so, I expect you can based on reading the [documentation](http://gabriel.github.io/gh-unit/). Try creating the test bundle as usual (if you don't already have one), and add the `GHUnit` target [according to the instructions](http://gabriel.github.io/gh-unit/docs/index.html). Then add your `SenTestCase` test files to the `GHUnit` target, and they should get run automatically by `GHUnit`.